# Angular - How to diagnose 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' fatal error at startup

Tags: angular

I've been having this sort of obscure error several times, always after modifying my Angular (2-5) dependencies.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at evaluate (http://localhost:5557/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1512143707276:2818:16)
    at http://localhost:5557/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1512143707276:3621:21
    at dynamicExecute (http://localhost:5557/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1512143707276:1142:26)
    at doEvaluate (http://localhost:5557/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1512143707276:1089:13)
    at ensureEvaluate (http://localhost:5557/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1512143707276:997:13)
    at http://localhost:5557/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1512143707276:1015:20
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:5557/app/app.module.js:15:14)
    at eval (http://localhost:5557/app/app.module.js:69:4)
    at eval (http://localhost:5557/app/app.module.js:70:3)
```

Where to start to get an idea of what's going on ?

Comment: I encountered this issue when the file trying to be loaded has all code commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, this helpless stacktrace originates in systemjs not being able to download a js file as it expects.

### Issue

In my case, the url requesting the js file is malformed, so the response should have been 404. But because my project is configured to redirect to the home page on 404, systemjs gets a response 200 and tries to interpret the html page as a javascript file. This is when the '<' hits the fan.

With that understanding, how to find out the offending request ?

### Diagnosis - Network

Looking at the 'network' tab of the browser devtool may help identify requests that look like js dependencies but have resolved to the home page (or any other html page).

### Diagnosis - Debug

When looking at network requests is impractical, debugging the systemjs calls is another option. How to find the right breakpoint ?

In Chromium, starting from the stacktrace available in the browser's console, I clicked on the first available element `evaluate(http://...)`. Trying to set a breakpoint here brought the debugger to another file, evaluate.js. There I was able to set a breakpoint and press F8 (resume) successively while keeping an eye on the `address` variable, until the stacktrace appeared: I had found the bad request.

### Fix

I am no expert in this matter, but it can be that some mapping hasn't been done properly, here's [an example from systemjs doc](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages).